# Estimating treatment effect using panel data and absorbing binary treatment

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, dynamic-regression, plm

I have a panel dataset of a large N and T = 24. I want to estimate the effect of a treatment (in this case, taking on a certain type of credit product) on Y which is an individuals credit score. I would also like to understand the time varying nature of the treatment - for example, can I determine if there is a negative effect in the immediate months post treatment/positive effect in the 6-12 months post treatment. The treatment variable is an absorbing binary treatment - that is if an individual $i$ takes out a this credit product in period $t$ then the dummy is set to 1 for all $it+1$.

My current thinking for modelling this is following a procedure similar to that outlined here https://comparativepopulationstudies.de/index.php/CPoS/article/view/468.

Essentially I have a two-way fixed effects model where each independent variable is dummy variable interacting the time period with whether the person was treated (e.g. TREAT_3 = 1 if a took out a product 3 months ago).

Alternatively, I was thinking of following a GMM procedure using the `plm` package in R e.g.

```r
model <- pgmm(credit_score ~ lag(credit_score, 1) + 
              credit_product_dummy |  lag(credit_score, 2:4), 
              data = panel, effect = "individual", 
              model = "twosteps")
```

But I am unsure how to use this to estimate the time from treatment effects.

Questions:

1. Given what I am trying to estimate, which of the 2 options would be preferable?
2. Are their any other modelling strategies I could use to get a better estimate? If so, could you please point me to literature where they are used.